# Do all parts of a plant contain the same type of cell?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology

I have only learned about the plant cell which is shown below. But plant stems alone are made up of different parts like xylem, phloem, parenchymatous cells, sclerenchymatous cells etc.

Are all the parts of a plant made up of cells like the one in this diagram or is the cell diagram changed for different parts of a plant?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The diagram shows an exemplary plant cell . Except for the raphide/druse crystals, which I do not know, all of these components are definitely present in every plant cell. Do note that this diagram is only an example and while it describes the *basic* components present in the cells, details can vary, since plants can have highly specialised vacuoles or plastids (like chloroplasts) in special cell types.

As @AlanBoyd pointed out, there are some specialised cases like the Sieve Tube cells, that do not have a nucleus. But in your average cell, you should find all of the components described in the diagram.

The differences between cell types are typically caused by the expression of different genes, that change the behaviour of each cell, and not directly by a change of how the cell is build up.

Comment: Do root hair cells contain chloroplasts?

Comment: Sieve tube elements (phloem) are anucleate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_tube_element?wprov=sfsi1

Comment: @AlanBoyd True, must cells in the roots will not have Chloroplasts. They will, however, have Leukoplasts instead, which are very similar and so the diagram as 'base plant cell' still holds.
The Sieve tube's I didn't know about before (see edit)